# Failed to call solidity function with array argument

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to execute contract's function use abi encode and `call` function, but I'm getting an error. Don't know how to resolve this issue.

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract AbiTest {

    event A(uint);
    event Out(bytes);

    function test() public {
        bytes4 func = bytes4(keccak256("callMe(uint[])"));

        uint[] memory arr = new uint[](3);
        arr[0] = 3;
        arr[1] = 4;

        (bool res, bytes memory data) = address(this).call(abi.encode(func, arr));
        emit Out(data);
        require(res);
    }

    function callMe(uint[] memory array) public {
            emit A(array[0]);
            emit A(array[1]);
    }
}
```

This solution works well, if arguments sizes are known at compile time, but with dynamic sizes this doesn't work.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use `abi.encodePacked` [see Solidity doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html#non-standard-packed-mode) instead of `abi.encode` because second one don't compress items and therefore uses 32 bytes for the function name.

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract Abi2Test {

    function getByte() public returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes4 func = bytes4(keccak256("callMe(uint256[])"));
        return abi.encode(func);
     }

    function getByte2() public returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes4 func = bytes4(keccak256("callMe(uint256[])"));
        return abi.encodePacked(func);
     }
}
```

`getByte` output: `0x6600981c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

`getByte2` output: `0x6600981c`

Therefore, when you use `encode` with function signature additionally will be allocated 28 bytes and EVM can't correctly parse passed value.

So, to correctly call function with `abi.encode` and `abi.encodePacked` you need to pack arguments with encode at the first, and at the second group function's signature with encoded bytes.

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

contract Abi2Test {

    event A(uint256);
    event Out(bytes);
    event Out1(bytes);

    function test() public {
        bytes4 func = bytes4(keccak256("callMe(uint256[])"));

        uint256[] memory arr = new uint256[](3);
        arr[0] = 3;
        arr[1] = 4;


        (bool res, bytes memory data) = address(this).call(abi.encodePacked(func, abi.encode(arr)));
        emit Out(data);
        require(res);
    }

    function callMe(uint256[] memory array) public {
            emit A(array.length);
            emit Out1(msg.data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution should work just fine. This is compatible with dynamic array lengths.

```
function test() public {
            uint[] memory arr = new uint[](2);
            arr[0] = 3;
            arr[1] = 4;
    
            (bool success, ) = address(this).call
                  (
                    abi.encodeWithSignature(
                        "callMe(uint[])",
                        arr
                  )
            );
         
}
```

Comment: no, this doesn't work, the transaction reverts, but solution here use this: ```bytes4 func = bytes4(keccak256("callMe(uint[])"));```, because Solidity implies under ```uint``` -> ```uint256```